# How do I open SSRS (.rptproj) files in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

How do I open .rptproj in Visual Studio 2013 Pro? When I try to open SSRS projects originally created in VS2008, in VS2013 I get:

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
```

Comment: How would they release VS2013 and not support SSRS? Shouldn't they be synched?

Comment: Yes, they should be synched, but aren't. please vote at this Microsoft Connect item to get an SSDT release for VS2013: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/806079/ssdt-bi-add-visual-studio-2013-support-to-sql-server-data-tools-for-business-intelligence

Comment: Can you tried install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313 and open .rptproj (created in ***VS 2008***) in **VS 2013** ? Can you design rdl file ? Note: originally rptproj created in VS 2008 and working for _SQL Server 2008R2_

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It can be opened with **Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence** for VS2013:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

The download is live again as of 6/2/14

Comment: Wow, never seen this before.  I go to download it and it serves up a "SSDT-BI Temporarily Unavailable.txt" file instead of the setup, and the contents says "SSDT-BI has been temporarily removed to deal with side by side issues with SSDT-SQL. We expect to have it reposted soon".  Hopefully REAL soon, I don't want to load up 2012. :( :( :(

Comment: Same here.  What a downer.  Trying to install BI stuff in my shiny new install of VS 2013, and now realizing I think i have to downgrade to VS2012.  The site still says SSDT-BI Temporarily Unavailable.

Comment: If you have an x64 SQL instance, be sure to select "Perform a new installation..." during the setup or you will run into an architecture mismatch failure. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989187/64-bit-microsoft-sql-server-data-tools

Answer (score 6):

You should install Business Intelligence Studio, it comes as part of MS SQL Server installation.

Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) — is a part of MS SQL Server. BIDS is a IDE for `rdl` reports development based on Visual Studio Shell. BIDS allows you to open `.rptproj` files. If you install BIDS on the same box with your regular Visual Studio, you will be able to open `.rptproj` and `.csproj` files from one IDE.

The issue is that SQL Server installations include BIDS based on previous version of Visual Studio Shell, i.e. SQL Server 2008 R2 will provide you BIDS integrated to Visual Studio 2008, while SQL Server 2012 BIDS will be based on Visual Studio 2010.

As far as I know, there is no BIDS that integrates into VS2013.

There is [version for VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36843).

SQL Server 2014 will ship BIDS based on VS2012 as well.

I believe we will see BIDS for VS2013 not earlier than in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 3):

SSRS is not a part of VS2013, it is part of SQL Server. You need the BI Dev Studio installed in order to be able to open SSRS projects (rptproj). It uses VS2013 just as a shell similar to what other products do...

Comment: the question key is about **Compatibility backwards**. I use **VS 2008 ** and **SQLServer 2008R2**, and SSRS (Reporting). I have SSRS project (.rptproj, I dont' know ProjectTypeGuid http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx) in VS 2008, and I can edit rdl files (diagram in editor). Can VS 2013 opens rptproj created in VS 2008 ? And edit .rdl files ?

Answer (score 3):

For **Visual Studio 2017** you need to download an install `SSDT for VS 2017 (standalone installer)` with `SQL Server Reporting Services`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017