# 64 bit Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssdt-bi

I am having trouble finding the 64 bit version of Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools.

Does any one know where i can download the **64 bit version** of Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2014.

I have only been able to find the following 32 bit version http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313 but i need the 64 bit version.

Comment: There is only a 32 bit version available. Visual Studio only comes in 32 bit and thus the reason why SSDT-BI is 32 bit. Read [this] for more clarity as to the reason/s why

[link] (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx)

Comment: What for? You ahve the non-existing 64 bit version of visual studio?

Comment: @TomTom, i have an existing 64 bit version of SQL Server 2014. And i need SQL Server Data Tools for SQL Server 2014, which requires visual studio 2013. See link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/03/25/sql-server-data-tools-for-sql-server-2014-is-available.aspx

Comment: @TomTom, never mind. g2server provided a working solution to my question. Thank you very much too, your posts have been very accommodating. :-)

Comment: For download links:- [link](http://all-downloadlinks.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

As the others have said, there is only a 32 bit version.

The important thing is, if you’re running an x64-based SQL instance (64-bit), make sure to select “New Instance” on the Installation Type page, and NOT “Add features to an existing instance”. Not doing so will cause it to error out.

Comment: Yeah, that's not confusing at all. Thanks for the tip. The "new instance" selection feels like you're re-installing SQL Server all over again. But it does work!

Comment: Good to see an answer to this that wasnt condescending!! +1 from me

Comment: In summation...
1. Download and run SSDTBI_x86_ENU
2. Step through and get to "Installation Type" then select "Perform a new installation of SQL Server 2014"
3. Select the features and finish out

Comment: Question on this answer: If I select "New Instance" as suggested, do I later need to reconfigure any software to point to the original instance?

Answer (score 2):

Only 32 bit version of SQL Server Data Tools published by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server comes in x32 and x64 but Visual Studio comes in only x32.

So if you have `x64 SQL Server 2014`, you can only install `SQL Server Data Tools x32` in a new instance configuration. This will install `Visual Studio 2013 x32`.

However if you have `SQL Server 2012`, `SQL Server Data Tools` are available in the installation media (unlike SQL 2014 where it has to be manually downloaded & installed).

Comment: unlike SQL 2014 where it has to be manually downloaded & installed... but where? because i´m looking for that without results, the best that i found was a x32 that fails because of my server is x64.